# how fix cycle in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have problem with cycle in djano(Maybe I dont understand this).I have cycle in template and it must to output value from database,but Idk how I can create cycle,which may output value from (id = 1),because this cycle output value (id = 0) again and again.

vds.html

```
{% for item in allobjects %}



  <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="body2">
      <li class="title">{{item.title}}</li>
      <li class="listram">{{item.ram}}<small>ГБ(озу)</small></li>
      <img class="ram2"width="51px" height="49px" src="/static/main/images/ram.png" ></img>
      <li class="cpu">{{item.cpu}} vCore</li>
      <img class="cpu1"width="51px" height="50px"  src="/static/main/images/cpu.png" ></img>
     <li class="hdd">{{item.hdd}}<small> ГБ(ssd)</small></li>
     <img class="hdd1"width="51px" height="50px" src="/static/main/images/hdd.png" ></img>
     <li class="os">Установка любой ос</li>
     <img  class="os1 " width="47px" height="49px"src="/static/main/images/os.png"/>
     <li class="os">Виртуализация KVM</li>
     <img  class="os1 " width="47px" height="49px"src="/static/main/images/vds.png"/>
     <form action="https://billing.king-host.ru">
         <button type="submit" name="buy">Купить</button>
         </form>
     <li class= "prise">{{item.name}}₽/месяц</li>
  </div>
  </div>


  <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="body3">
      <li class="title">{{item.title}}</li>
      <li class="listram"><small>ГБ(озу)</small></li>
      <img class="ram2"width="51px" height="49px" src="/static/main/images/ram.png" ></img>
      <li class="cpu">2 vCore</li>
      <img class="cpu1"width="51px" height="50px"  src="/static/main/images/cpu.png" ></img>
     <li class="hdd">40<small> ГБ(ssd)</small></li>
     <img class="hdd1"width="51px" height="50px" src="/static/main/images/hdd.png" ></img>
     <li class="os">Установка любой ос</li>
     <img  class="os1 " width="47px" height="49px"src="/static/main/images/os.png"/>
     <li class="os">Виртуализация KVM</li>
     <img  class="os1 " width="47px" height="49px"src="/static/main/images/vds.png"/>
     <form action="https://billing.king-host.ru">
         <button type="submit" name="buy">Купить</button>
         </form>
     <li class= "prise">600 ₽/месяц</li>
  </div>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

models.py

```
class VDSTARIFS( models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=40, primary_key= True,serialize=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name = 'Цены')
    choosen = models.CharField(max_length= 20, choices = CHOOSE, verbose_name = 'Тариф', help_text='Выбор тарифного плана.')
    title = models.CharField(max_length= 15)
    ram = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    hdd = models.CharField(max_length= 10)
    cpu = models.CharField(max_length=10)
   
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)
```

views.py

```
def vds(request):
    servers = VDSTARIFS.objects.all() ##Maybe filter 
    context1 = {
        'allobjects': servers
    }
    return render(request,'vds.html',context1)
```

Comment: Your files actually seem ok. Are you sure you have different objects in database? Why do you have `id` field as `Charfield`? There might be a problem.

Comment: You don't need id when you are defining a model, because `models.Model` already as that and it will auto increment.  Based on what I see, you are not auto incrementing the primary key, so it might be getting overwritten every time.

Comment: @ja408 Thanks you :) I solved my problem

Comment: @NixonSparrow Thanks you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `views.py` to return values for `id=1` as

```
def vds(request):
    servers = VDSTARIFS.objects.filter(id=1)
    context1 = {
        'allobjects': servers
    }
    return render(request, 'vds.html', context1)
```

Comment: And how can I get id = 0?)I need to get id =0 and id = 1 and e.t.c

Comment: If you want all data then your code is right

Comment: but its not working)When I want to do secont tarif and output {{item.title}} for second tarif,it output id = 0.

Comment: Probably I have problems with database. I think,I'll try to fix it.

Comment: It isnt problem with database

Comment: Can I ask you? How Can I fix it? https://imgur.com/AnCcsjs
They merged into one.

Comment: Try keeping your `<li>` tags inside `<ul>` tags

Comment: it isnt help :(

Comment: I made a crutch in the code, but it works
    servers = VDSTARIFS.objects.all()[:1](I need to use for and I have done it, if I didnt use for I used objects.get)
In any way,Thanks you :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem, problem was because of wrong request.If someone will have this problem, solving this problem was used slices

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).